# How to display two values in two inputs?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two inputs, I have a minimum value and a maximum value.

My problem is that I would like that inside each input there are values...

For example:

For the input `minimum value` I must display `.00`

and for the `maximum value` I must display `9999999999999.99`.

Below, here is an image illustration. I absolutely want the same result, please.

[image]

template

```
<form #formulaire="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="getOverviewTotalAmount()">
<div class=" row mb-4 align-items-end ">
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 ">
      <div class="mb-2 ">
         <!-- Minimum value  -->
         <h5>Minimum value</h5>
         <input type="number" class="form-control form-max-width" [(ngModel)]="model.valoMin" name="valoMin" required />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 ">
      <div class="mb-2 ">
         <!-- Maximum value -->
         <h5>Maximum value</h5>
         <input type="number" class="form-control form-max-width" [(ngModel)]="model.valoMax" name="valoMax" required />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12 col-md-4 ">
      <div class="mb-2 ">
         <button type="submit " class="btn btn-success btn_green_arg ">
            <!-- Search -->
            Search
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</form>
```

class

```
export class Amount {
  amount: string;
  valoMin: number | null; 
  valoMax: number | null; 

  constructor() {
    this.amount = '';
    this.valoMax = null; 
    this.valoMin = null; 
  }

  validateMinMax(): boolean {
    return this.valoMin == null || this.valoMax == null || this.valoMin <= this.valoMax;
  }
}
```

composent

```
export class OverviewTotalAmountComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();
  currentAgency: any;
  overviewTotalAmountResponse: OverviewTotalAmountResponse;

  model: Amount = new Amount();
  valoMin: number;
  valoMax: number;

  constructor(
    private service: OverviewTotalAmountService,
    private store: Store,
    private router: Router
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.currentAgency = this.store.selectSnapshot(AgencyState.currentAgency);
      if (this.currentAgency) {
        this.getOverviewTotalAmount();
      }
    }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }

  getOverviewTotalAmount(): void {
    this.service
      .getOverviewTotalAmount(this.model)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe((res) => {
        if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
          this.overviewTotalAmountResponse = res as OverviewTotalAmountResponse;
          this.valoMin = this.model.valoMin !== null ? this.model.valoMin : 0;
          this.valoMax = this.model.valoMax !== null ? this.model.valoMax : 0;
        }
      });
  }

  
  
}
```

I thank you in advance for your help and the time devoted to my problem, because I am really stuck.

Comment: are you just trying to get the initial value to display before user interaction, or are you trying to specify the decimal places?

Comment: I just want in the input the value `.99` to appear please

Comment: hard to tell what you are asking. but if you want valoMin to display .99, why are you setting it to null? set it to `this.valoMin = .99;`

Comment: Actually, I changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hard to figure out what you are trying to do, but try this;

```
constructor() {
this.amount = '';
this.valoMax = 9999999999999.99; 
this.valoMin = .99; 
  }
```

and html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-max-width" [(ngModel)]="model.valoMin" name="valoMin" placeholder=".99" value=".99" required />
```

Note change your type to text if you want values other than ints

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works halfway. I see `0.99` and `9999999999999.99` :S If you have a solution, I'm still interested.

Comment: so which part is not working?

Comment: Thanks for your help, just the `.99`, I always show `0.99`.

Comment: hmm that's not even possible because you are displaying it as text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'value' attribute on html element:

```html
<!-- miniaml value -->
<input type="number" class="form-control form-max-width" value=0.00 [(ngModel)]="model.valoMin" name="valoMin" required />
<!-- ... -->
<!-- maximal value -->
<input type="number" class="form-control form-max-width" value=9999999999999.99 [(ngModel)]="model.valoMax" name="valoMax" required />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have the same problem.

Comment: @amelabamelab440 what exactly is the issue? is it not showing the default value when the element loads or is it different on the form submission?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't show the default when loading. I want to see `.99` and I see `0.99`, I feel like it doesn't want to remove the `0`

Answer (score 1):

Use the value attribute like the other poster indicated but I would also include the step attribute if you need the decimal places for the form data

`<input  value="0.99" step=0.01 type='number' />`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I still see `0.99``, I want to display `.99`

Comment: did you try changing it to `value=".99"`? and change the `type='text'`

Comment: @amelabamelab440 ah i think it may be an issue with your model bindings. Try setting the default value for your Ng Model to match what you want to initially display